# How to constrain VHDL-2008 integer_vector?

Tags: vhdl

VHDL-2008 defines

```
type integer_vector is array (natural range <>) of integer
```

and it can be used to create arrays of unconstrained integers just fine:

```
signal sUnconsrainedIntA : integer_vector(0 to 1) := (others => 0);
```

However, how to declare array of constrained integers, e.g:

```
-- does not work:
-- signal sConstrainedTestIntA : integer_vector(0 to 1) range 0 to 3 := (others => 0);
-- ** Error: filetest.vhd(65): Range constraints cannot be applied to array types.
-- ** Error: filetest.vhd(65): Range expression is type Integer; expecting type std.STANDARD.INTEGER_VECTOR

-- What you can do is:
type my_int_array is array (natural range <>) of integer range 0 to 3;
signal sConstrainedIntA : my_int_array(0 to 1) := (others => 0);
```

Is there a way to constrain the integers in the array without the custom type?

Comment: I guess not. `integer_vector` is an array of integers with full range, as you wrote. If you want to change that, you have to define a different type by yourself.

Comment: How about defining a custom type that then can be constrained later, like   

  type slv_array is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;
signal sSlvA : slv_array(0 to 1)(1 downto 0) := (others => (others => '0'));

Comment: I'm not sure about VHDL-2008, but before, you couldn't do such thing. And I guess it is still not possible with VHDL-2008.

Comment: Type `integer` is a constrained type (scalar type, numeric type), whereas `std_logic_vector` is a unconstrained array type of an enumeration type (`std_logic`).

Answer (score 2):

VHDL 2008 supports package generic parameters. You could try something like:

```
package foo_pkg is
    generic(l, h: integer);
    subtype my_integer is integer range l to h;
    type my_integer_vector is array(natural range <>) of my_integer;
end package foo_pkg;

package foo_pkg_m17_p39 is new work.foo_pkg
    generic map(l => -17, h => 39);

package foo_pkg_p57_p134 is new work.foo_pkg
    generic map(l => 57, h => 134);

entity foo is
    port(iv1: work.foo_pkg_m17_p39.my_integer_vector(0 to 7);
         iv2: work.foo_pkg_p57_p134.my_integer_vector(0 to 7)
     );
end entity foo;
```

Not very user friendly because you need one package instantiation declaration per integer constraint. But it is what I found that resembles most what you ask for...

Even if it looks more complicated than what you expected, it still allows you to factorize your custom code for all variants of my_integer_vector.